# Is it possible to use core processors instead of xeon?

Tags: cpu, performance, intel-core-i7, xeon

We need to include QSV feature in deployment. We just thought of having i5/i7 processors instead of Xeon. Because they are having QSV feature as default. So we thought instead of using C226 chipset for QSV support in Xeon, its better to use i5/i7 processors.

So my question is, is it possible to use core processors instead of Xeon. Will it be feasible? If so, how the speed would be?

As of now, Xeon E5 v4 is under use. If the replacement processor is i3/5/7, how it would affect the factors like speed, caching capacity, etc?

Is rack mount PCs available having i3/5/7 processors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes it is possible, but I do expect it to be suboptimal in many cases. one major concern, is that Xeon's implement technologies to allow more than one physical chip per box, which the PC line of chips do not support. if you are planning a multi-socket box, you won't be able to achieve that without server grade chips.

Comment: ok. thanks. is there rack type CPUs available having i5/i7 processors? @ Frank Thomas

Comment: And is there any core processors equivalent for E5 Xeon V4?

Comment: I removed the prompt for hardware recommendations, it’s off-topic. Your question also does not give any context at all, so it cannot be answered. What’s the use? What “chipsets for every feature in Xeon”? Is it about existing machines/hardware?

Comment: @DanielB For example if we need QSV feature we need to have C226 chipset. Because it is not available in default with Xeon. But we dont need any chipset for that feature in core processors

Comment: I just need to know whether there are equivalents are not. its yes or no. Its not about hardware recommendations

Comment: No there aren’t, simply because i3/5/7 don’t support ECC. That is why your specific requirements are important! So please do include them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, for transcoding, you want to have fast and large caches and/or many cores. You don't really need Error Code Correction (ECC), which is mostly available only with Xeon Processors. Some Xeon Processors in the E3 range do have iGPUs, these support Intel Quick Sync Video.

Probably the best of all those processors should be the [Broadwell based Xeon with eDRAM](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10361/intel-announces-xeon-e3-1500-v5-iris-pro-and-edram-for-streaming-video). Your can also read a [review](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9532/the-intel-broadwell-xeon-e3-v4-review-95w-65w-35w-1285-1285l-1265) about this Xeon lineup processors at a respected site. These are not very easy to get, you could contact [ixsystems.com](http://ixsystems.com) for that. People like Alan Jude of [BSDNOW.tv](http://www.bsdnow.tv/) fame is a professional, who would be happy to talk to you about that I guess. This is in my opinion one of the best solutions to your problem.

You could of course also use the [Xeon D](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9185/intel-xeon-d-review-performance-per-watt-server-soc-champion), which has 8 cores and is available with appropriate boards from Supermicro, Asrock, Gigabyte and others.

In any case, I wouldn't use consumer processors for serious deployment unless you really know, what you are doing. But hey, then you wouldn't ask around at SuperUser.

Comment: ya its just a thought. I need to be clarified. For using C226 chipset we need to configure our xeon default settings itself. there were many procedures. for a confirmation i asked this question. And thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Well, if you have any trouble with your systems, one of the best ways would be to phone ixsystems and tell them what you have in mind. They will custom build machines for you for suprisingly low amounts of money. They will setup the BIOS/ UEFI as you please and they will very cauciosly test your harddrives for 36 hours. They can also get you pretty much any CPU from Intel.

Answer (score 0):

[Article](http://www.velocitymicro.com/blog/xeon-vs-i7i5-whats-difference/)

Pros of i7/i5:

- Overclocking, if you have an unlocked one.
- Ghz per dollar they are cheaper.
- On board graphics is present.

Pros of Xeon:

- L3 cache, usually double that of an i range alternative. Speeds up some applications
- ECC RAM, can catch corruption when it occurs and not bring down your system because of a bit flip. Also prevent saving wrong data to harddrive. A second bit flip in a page is detected, but cannot be corrected. You don't write wrong data to disk.
- More cores & multi cpu support.
- Longevity under load
- Lower price point hyper threading. (All xeons have hyper threading, not all i's do.

[This](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Intel-CPUs-Xeon-E5-vs-Core-i7-634/) Website does a review of comparable xeon to i7, albiet for a xeon v3

Their conclusion is:

- Clock per clock identical performance
- Larger range of Xeons with a wider range of frequencies and cores available
- Higher ram capacity on the Xeons.
- You dont need a server board for the Xeon they were using. (Because Xeon E3 are the same die as Core i5 and i7 with different features anabled/ disabled.)

Comment: No worries, if you need clarification let me know, otherwise feel free to mark as accepted!

Comment: sure. still having one doubt. Is rack type CPUs available having i5/i7 processors?

Comment: Good question, I'll look to confirm and update my answer. My hunch would be if it has the same socket it will work.

Comment: I can't find a definitive answer, some one with knowledge in the area may need to chime in.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "rack type CPUs". There are boards, which will happily take Xeon E3 and Core i5/ Core i7 and even Core i3 of the same generation. Look for Supermicro boards for instance. Just be sure, it is the same socket (CPU generation).